# Initialize NSArray with dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

How to Initialize an Array with Dictionary having key as string and value as boolean value.Some thing like this

```
array = @[@{@"fieldX": @FALSE, @"fieldY": @FALSE},@{@"fieldX": @FALSE, @"fieldY": @FALSE}                    ];
```

but i don't understand what is key and what is value in above.

Comment: you need to make array out off keys or values ?

Comment: Didn't get what you are asking

Comment: first is values and second is key

Comment: Exactly the opposite, first is key, second is value! In this case fieldX is the key (in the array's element, which is the dictionary). And the value that belongs to fieldX is @FALSE

Comment: Can you tell us what the dataset is currently and what the desired result should look like?

Answer (score 1):

You may do this:

```
NSArray *array = @[
                   @{
                       @"fieldX" : @(NO),
                       @"fieldY" : @(NO)
                       },
                   @{
                       @"fieldX" : @(NO),
                       @"fieldY" : @(NO)
                       }
                   ];

BOOL secondFieldX = [[array[1] valueForKey:@"fieldY"] boolValue];
```

You may use a model object instead dictionaries anyway, but that's another story.

Comment: Indeed, some extra white space and indentation makes things much easier to follow. You have an outer array that contains 2 dictionaries. Each dictionary contains keys "fieldX" and "fieldY", all of which contain values of NO/FALSE (NO and FALSE are synonyms.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this....

```
array_office_list=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
            if (i==0) {
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"address"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"phone"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"email"];
                [array_office_list addObject:dict];
            }
            if (i==1) {
                 [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"address"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"phone"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"email"];
                [array_office_list addObject:dict];
            }
            if (i==2) {
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"address"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"phone"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"email"];
                [array_office_list addObject:dict];
            }
            if (i==3) {
                 [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"name"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"address"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"phone"];
                [dict setObject:@"" forKey:@"email"];
                [array_office_list addObject:dict];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created an Array with 2 NSDictionaries within.
This is how a NSDictionary is created with the syntax above: `@{key:value , key:value , key:value}`
This is how a NSArray is created with the syntax above: `@[object , object , object]`

In your example.
The first NSDictionary has two keys: `fieldX` and `fieldY` both with a BOOL value of NO/FALSE
The second NSDictonary has the same key-values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
+[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys];
```

to initialize a dictionary from arrays...

If you want to grab all keys or values from dictionary you can do like this

```
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
```

Which can be used to create a new array containing a combination if desired.